# Finding Residue Classes

Tags: number-theory

Can someone explain to me how to find all the elements in $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15}$

Wouldnt the solutions be:

$[1], [2], [7], [11], [13]$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{15}$ denotes the multiplicative group of units in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$, whose elements are exactly the classes modulo $n$ of integers coprime to $n$, hence
$$[1],[2],[4],[7],[8],[11],[13],[14]$$

The group of units $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{15}$ is finite abelian of order $8$, there is a structure theorem for finite abelian groups, giving a decomposition in direct product of cyclic groups, in your case: $\mathbb{Z}_{15}^{*}=\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4$ (up to isomorphisms), then notice that $[2]$ has order $4$ and $[14]$ has order $2$, thus they generate each cyclic component $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ of $\mathbb{Z}_{15}^{*}$

Comment: Okay, then how do I find $a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{Z}^*_{15}$ such that $\mathbb{Z}^*_{15} = <a_1, a_2>$

Comment: @Steven try with $a_1=[2]$ and $a_2=[14]$

Comment: I dont want just an answer, mind explaining?

Comment: Play around a little with the given residue classes: can you what abelian group is that? Can you then see why you need two generators, one of order two and the other one of order 4?

Comment: @Steven added an edit to the answer

Comment: I am confused as to how you find the order 8?

Comment: Ohhh, order = number of elements.

Comment: @Steven order of a finite group=number of elements in the group; order of an element $a$ of a finite group $G$= smallest exponent $n$ such that $a^n=e$. Note that the order of an element divides the order of the group (by Lagrange)